# add folder to home directory

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory

Instructions on the [airwave github](https://github.com/phantom-code/airwave) requires me to download and install the Audio Plugins SDK.

This step confuses me as new Ubuntu user:

> Unpack the VST SDK archive. Further I'll assume that you have unpacked it in your home directory: `${HOME}/VST3\ SDK.`

I have two options:

1. Create a folder in home directory. I am unable to do that and my guess it has to do with root privileges. I believe it is recommended to use `sudo` for temporary access root privileges? I don’t know what command to use or how to create a folder in home directory otherwise
2. Use another folder in my user directory, but can someone explain the following `${HOME}/VST3\ SDK.`. What is with the slash and backslash etc. Can someone explain? I wouldn’t know how to direct the command to my user  directory in here:

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/airwave -DVSTSDK_PATH=${HOME}/VST3\ SDK ..
   ```

Since I am a new user to Ubuntu some basic explanation would do me well.

Thank you for your time and answers

Comment: You should have no problem creating a new folder in your home directory.  Can you run `ll /home | grep [your user name here]`, and post the output for your user directory?

As far as what the slashes mean, the `/` just breaks up the folders in the path, and `\` is an escape that allows you to use spaces in terminal.

Comment: ... remember `${HOME}` is not the same thing as `/home`

Comment: drwx------ 31 sokolov sokolov 12288 jan 12 17:01 sokolov/
 Is this the expected output?

Comment: Im sorry with slash i understand, but the combination of slash and backslash confuses me. Usually it is only slash, now what does backslash or the combination /VST3\ mean?

Comment: @sokolov: `\ ` backslash-space is a quoted space. `${HOME}/VST3\ SDK` is the same thing as `${HOME}/"VST3 SDK"`.

Comment: @sokolov The backslash "escapes" the character after it, which takes away its special meaning. In this case, it's telling the shell to ignore the space, because it's part of the directory name.

Comment: @ServiceManager By the way, the simpler way to get the same output is `ll -d ~`

Comment: What's the output of `LC_MESSAGES=POSIX mkdir -v ${HOME}/VST3\ SDK`?

Comment: @Service Manager drwx------ 31 sokolov sokolov 12288 jan 12 17:01 /home/sokolov/      is the output. The create folder option in home is greyed out. Currently greyed out.

How can I create that folder now please?

Comment: @David Foerster that command basically created a folder in my /home/user and the folder name is "VST3 SDK" 
If that is what you asked me?

I think I now understand the backslash with you explanation guys.

Steeldriver's point helps me understand that {Home} is not the same as /home, but the result I get from David's command is a folder in /user, so what does {...} mean actually?

Comment: See the first three paragraphs of https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html. Bottom line: `${HOME}` is substituted with the value of the environment variable `HOME`, which should be the path name of the home directory of the current user. On Ubuntu that's typically "/home/${USER}", where `USER` is the name of the current user account, e. g. for me it might be `foersterd`.

Answer (score 1):

${HOME} means your home directory which is /home/username by default. Simply create a new Folder there named "VST3 SDK" and unpack the archive there.

The "\ " is used to indicate a whitespace, because if you would use a terminal command a whitespace also seperates arguments.

Answer (score -3):

To create a folder in home, do the following:

1. Open up the terminal
2. You should already be in home (if not, do: `cd ~`)
3. `mkdir <folder_name>` or `sudo mkdir <folder_name>`

Comment: Why would you need to use sudo in your home directory?